# Can PostgreSQL manage a table with 1.5 billion rows?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-12, query-performance

The table has three columns:

- `id`
- `string` (up to 400 characters)
- `length` which records the length of `string`

The problem was, when I do a query, e.g.

```
select * from table where length = <whatever number>;
```

PostgreSQL never returns, it keeps calculating.

I was wondering if that was due to the large data set?

Should I somehow split the table into several?

Environment: 12GB RAM, PostgreSQL 12 on Win10.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the table definition as a `create table` statement including all indexes (as `create index` statements) and the execution plan generated with `explain select ...` as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. What is your exact Postgres version? (`select version();` will tell you)

Comment: To answer the (too broad) question: yes, Postgres can handle tables that large. But tuning it can be a challenge (and typically Postgres performs better on Linux). What kind of hardware are you using? Especially what kind of harddisk and how many?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's 12.1^^, and the disk is WD with 1 TB.

Comment: So, a **single** spinning harddisk (rather than a SSD)? You will have a hard time getting a decent performance out of that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am creating the index right now but it still runs, my program really need the speed, will it improves a lot by using SSD with index according to your experience?

Comment: Yes, SSDs make a huge difference when your database is far bigger than your memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have more patience, scanning a large table takes a while.

The classical remedy is to create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "table" (length);
```

That will take a long time itself (and might use considerable disk space), but once you have that index, it will speed up your query (unless it returns so many rows that an index scan is no more efficient than a sequential table scan).

An alternative might be to [partition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) the table according to length. That would require that the length hardly ever changes. Then each search for a certain string length would scan only the appropriate partition and be as fast as possible. Try to get fast disks.

Comment: Thanks, I am doing it. The data I have, has around 100GB, which should take hours right? And I am wondering how fast it can be? My program would actually search the strings with certain length with a loop of 10-20, would it speed up, if I split the large dataset into several tables by using ```CREATE TABLE table01 ( ) INHERITS (length);```? Because alone to read the data from csv file and store them to databank took me more than two days, I would better ask someone's suggestion first^^ Thank you very much

Comment: You could partition the data according to length. That would make sense. I have added that to the answer.

Comment: actually, would db itself create an index for a table? would it help if I create an index on strings after the partition?

Comment: The database never creates an index by itself, except to back a unique, primary key or exclusion constraint. If you partition the table according to string lengths, you would need no index on the string length. An index on the string is only useful if you use it in a `WHERE` condition.